# How can I prevent Firefox from switching to search tab?

Tags: firefox, google-search

In Firefox when you highlight *Some Text* and click right mouse button there is option `Search Google for "Some text"`. It is all nice, but Firefox switches to the search tab immediately, how do I prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type 'about:config' in the address bar, find 'browser.search.context.loadInBackground' in the list of settings, double click on the preference name to make the boolean value TRUE.